# How to retrieve the xml nodes,elements attributes in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml

I need to retrieve the different nodes  attributes values   and that attributes values are stored into different three dropdownlists..how to do this ..thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post your xml file and describe which one of the three attributes must be the value and which must be the text?

Answer (score 0):

From your post I cannot see if it should be the same values in every dropdownlist, but in that case:

The XMLFile.xml

```
<Elements>
  <Element id="1" name="Test" />
  <Element id="2" name="Test2" />
</Elements>
```

And bit a dropdownlist to it:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="namesXML" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id" />

<asp:XmlDataSource ID="namesXML" runat="server" DataFile="~/XMLFile.xml" />
```

Comment: I want to store 3 xml elements attributes values into 3 different dropdownlist.....plz help me...thanks in advance